# Create a function that checks characters?

Tags: function, scheme

I've been thinking about how I create a function in scheme that builds itself depending on an input.

The way a character is defined in scheme is #(character here), so if I were to check, with a function, if my character is indeed a character, I would have to take the input from the function and insert it instead of (character here), and make it work.

I am not sure how this is done, if I input a random character without the #\, I get that it is an undefined function, so how do I do this?

```
(define check-char?
   (lambda (v)
        (char? #\v)))
```

that is what I have, but as said, this is not working.

Comment: Hint: `symbol->string`

Comment: Please provide several sample inputs/expected outputs of what you intend to do. Exactly, what data types are going to be used as inputs?

Comment: Also notice: the question is a bit nonsensical, if you somehow put a  #\ in front of _something_, that _something_ **will** be interpreted as a character, hence asking `char?` will always return true for it - it won't matter what's the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A character is a value. How exactly the value is stored in memory varies from from implementation to implementation. If we as programmers want to create a character we can do it various ways:

If we know ahead of time what character we need, we can use the literal syntax: `#\x` . When the reader reads the program, it will construct a character representing the letter `x`.

The actual character is stored in memory as a number. If we know that number, we can also produce an `x` using `integer->char`.

```
> (integer->char 120)
#\x
```

Strings are made from series of characters, so we can also produce characters using `string-ref`:

```
> (string-ref "x" 0)
#\x
```

The procedure used to check whether a value is a character is called `char?`.

```
> (char? #\x)
#t
> (char? (string-ref "x" 0))
#t
```

Your `check-char?` command can be written as:

(define check-char?
     (lambda (v)
       (char? v)))

Or simply as:

```
 (define check-char? char?)
```

Let's test it:

```
> (check-char? #'x)
#t
> (check-char? 3)
#f
```

Comment: Thanks, that was a very good explaination of how it worked! :)